# General CSS for #id ending with numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will start with an example

I have something like this. Same id name with different ending numbers.

```
#samplelist_1 { color: #fff; }
#samplelist_2 { color: #fff; }
#samplelist_3 { color: #fff; }
#samplelist_4 { color: #fff; }
```

and these css are automatically generated. So I want to declare and define a css for #samplelist_.. which will affect all the #ids generally. So any #ids generated say: _15, _86 or anything like that can be styled.

Is that possible?

Comment: It would be far easier to give the elements a `class="samplelist"` and place `.samplelist { color: #fff; }` in the .css

Comment: Don't worry it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the attribute starts-with selector:

```
[id^="samplelist_"] {
    color: white;
}
```

Better yet, give them a class.

Comment: Almost same answer :) but I don't want to delete my answer :(

Comment: Please can you explain it more. Do I need to use [id^="samplelist_"] as it is

Comment: This selector matches all elements with an `id` attribute that starts with `samplelist_`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't generate such redundant styles, instead use class to apply same style to multiple element at once. Thus, eliminating the need to go look for such *stupid solution* on first place.

If not going for cross-browser compatible CSS then you can do something like

```
[id^="samplelist_"] {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Let me explain this selector in detail

- `[id]`: means it is going to match the `id` attribute of the element
- `^=`: means if the value starts with `....`

Combined it says "if `id` starts with `samplelist_`" then apply this style.

Comment: CSS attribute selectors are supported by all browsers aside from IE6 and below.

Comment: @Blender, Many or few, It still is not a cross-browser compatible solution.